# Apache Commons IO - Encrypt download from Website

Tags: java, apache, download

With Apache Commons Io you can download Files from the Internet (`FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL, File)`). But is this download encrypted? If no how can I encrypt a download from the Internet?

PS: I want to download from a Website/Filehost like Mediafire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague - therefore I made the assumption you are referring to an encrypted transfer of the download when you are talking about an "encrypted download".

If this is wrong the answer is simply: It depends on the file-format. Encryption of file-level is not standardized.

A download is transferred encrypted (and integrity protected) if it uses SSL/TLS - hence if it is transferred via HTTPS in case of a download.

Therefore it depends on the used URL if your download is "encrypted" or not. Note that your client automatically decrypts the received data. Therefore you don't notice that a download has been encrypted while in transit.